# Does it matter what gender I fall in love with?

Tags: rune-factory-4

I noticed that in the "BTW..."  menu I get when talking to people, I can declare that I love them. I am not entirely sure what effect that has,  but does it matter who I say it to? Can I, as a girl, say it to another girl and get the same effects as saying it to a male character?

Comment: I may have to "test" this in my game. Pretty sure there are some guys that would say yes...

Comment: Any idea what it does when you do?

Comment: Not a clue. Hence why I will need to test.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot date a character with the same gender as you.

If the character has a relationship level of at least 7 and is a candidate for dating, you will begin dating them. You can see which characters are suitable for dating by looking at the relationship panel. Those suitable for dating will have 1-10 hearts denoting your relationship level, everyone else will have stars.

If you say "I love you" to someone who is not a valid candidate (too young, old, wrong gender, etc), not around level 7 relationship, or just a bad day (possibly some unknown reason) they will just take it as a joke. There is no option for a homosexual relationship.